# Is the size in a Word2Vec model equal to the max input size of a sentence?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

This might seem like a trivial question to many but its not clear for me.

So i have a model that looks like this

```
w2v_model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec(size=300, 
                                        window=7, 
                                        min_count=10, 
                                        workers=8)
```

I also tokenize my x_train and x_test like this

```
x_train = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df_train.text), maxlen=300)
x_test = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df_test.text), maxlen=300)
```

My embedding layer looks like this

```
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size, 300), dtype='float32')
 for word, i in tokenizer.word_index.items():
  if word in w2v_model.wv:
    embedding_matrix[i] = w2v_model.wv[word]

embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=300, 
trainable=False)
```

So I get that the 300 in the model is the dimension size and the 300 in the pad_sequences is the max sequence length aka max sentence length

I also get that the 300 in the embedding_matrix definition is the w2v dimension size again and that the first 300 in the embedding_layer is referring to the w2v dimension size

and the second 300 would be the max input length aka the same as the max length in the pad_sequences but what I don't get is.

If my dimensional size of my w2v model equals to let's say 240, does this mean my pad_sequences maxlen should also be 240 and also the input_length in my embedding_layer?

For example, the w2v size is 300 but my sentence length that I want to predict is 360 and my pad_sequences maxlen would be 500. Would my neural net be able to correctly predict this sentence of length 360?

Comment: Maxlen is just the maximum number of tokens in your sentence, this is requires for so the layers can properly create the architecture. You can use a w2v model with embedding dim of 300 to predict a sentence of 360 training with maxlen of 500, don't mix apple with oranges.

Comment: Yes okay, this is what I thought. So the dimension size has nothing to do with the sentence length" @jcaliz correct?

Comment: Not at all, w2v is just a representation of a token in an D-dimensional space in this case (and normally) 300 and sentence length is the number of token.